# Estimator choice for mapping string independent variable to string categorical dependent variable

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, data-science

I'm attempting to build a predictive model that can map text-based vendor-provided descriptions of a service to around 800 standardized service codes, based on a training set of about 13,000 correctly mapped services.

Each standardized service code also has a standardized description, which is usually similar to the vendor-provided description (i.e, some of the words used are the same), but not identical. Descriptions are typically 3-10 word in length

My main issue is that I'm not sure what type of estimator will be appropriate for this problem.

I have tried using simple fuzzy matching approaches, including:

- Counting matching words/characters between the vendor-provided and standardized service descriptions and selecting the one with the most matches
- Trying to find the standardized service description with the minimum Levenshtein distance

These have not worked particularly well due to the use of synonymous but different word choices within the vendor-provided and standardized descriptions.

I have also considered using a decision tree, but it seems infeasible given 800+ possible outcomes.

Which type of estimator can I use to solve this problem?

Comment: You can first use a summarization technique to extract the most useful words from the description and then use a word embedding technique like word2vec to calculate the similarity between the summary words and the service codes choosing the service code which is most similar. Simple word distance techniques like Levenshtein distance won't work well here because of synonyms

Comment: Thanks for that @Ken4scholars. Are there any specific summarization techniques that you can recommend?

Comment: You can do an extractive summarization using TF-IDF to calculate the relevance of each word in the description and rank them, then select the highest ranked word

Comment: Got it, thank you very much @Ken4scholars